# Populate form from JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to re-populate a form from some values in localStorage. I can't quite manage the last part to get the loop to populate my name and values.

```
 function loadFromLocalStorage() {
    PROCESS_SAVE = true;

    var store = localStorage.getItem(STORE_KEY);
    var jsn = JSON.parse(store);
    console.log(jsn);

    if(store.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    var s = jsn.length-1;
    console.log(s);
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var formInput = s[i];
        console.log(s[i]);

        $("form input[name='" + formInput.name +"']").val(formInput.value);
    }
}
```

[image: result of console]

Could I get some pointers please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this section of code.

```
var s = jsn.length-1;
console.log(s);
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
```

You are setting `s` to the `length` of the `jsn` array minus `1`, then using it as if it were `jsn`. I think you intended something like this.

```
function loadFromLocalStorage() {
    PROCESS_SAVE = true;

    var store = localStorage.getItem(STORE_KEY);
    var jsn = JSON.parse(store);
    console.log(jsn);

    if(store.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < jsn.length; i++) {
        var formInput = jsn[i];
        console.log(jsn[i]);

        $("form input[name='" + formInput.name +"']").val(formInput.value);
    }
}
```